Delta Lake Table - Merge command generates ONE huge file (3 GB or higher)
I have a Delta table, that when merging new data, will generate ONLY one HUGE file ( > 3 GB), per partition.
Create Session
builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("create_cdr_master_table") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    
spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

# Configure Spark Settings

# Default Delta File size
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.targetFileSize", "134217728")

Merge Data
print("Merging data")
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "telco.cdr_master_delta2")
deltaTable.alias("target").merge(new_cdr_raw_df.alias('source'), "target.uuid = source.uuid and target.date_string = source.date_string").whenMatchedUpdateAll().whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()


Optimize Table
In addition, after, when I try to optimize the table, it does nothing.
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

# Optimize Data
print("Optimize data")

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "telco.cdr_master_delta2")
# deltaTable.optimize().where("date_string='20240717'").executeCompaction(targetSize = 128 * 1024 * 1024) # Seems to be version problem, since doesn't accept targetSize param
deltaTable.optimize().where("date_string='20240717'").executeCompaction()

Questions

Does Delta Lake optimize command can convert HUGE files into normal size files? I

